# "Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0" when trying to POST web form data to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating an application with a web form that when the user clicks "submit", the data is added to a DynamoDB table.

My web form's HTML code includes an API (created using API Gateway) which triggers a Lambda function that should parse the data and Put it in DynamoDB. However, I'm getting an `Unexpected token Z in JSON at position 0` error when I submit the web form.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <body>
    <p>Sign-Up Form</p>
    <form action="https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/submit" method="post">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" required>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
          <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" required>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="region">Which region are you based in?</label>
          <select name="region" id="region" required>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="emea">EMEA</option>
            <option value="amer">AMER</option>
            <option value="apj">APJ</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li class="button">
          <button type="submit">Submit Sign-Up Form</button>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };

  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "POST /items":
        let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo
          .post({
            TableName: "XXXXXX",
            Item: {
              first_name: requestJSON.first_name,
              last_name: requestJSON.last_name,
              user_email: requestJSON.user_email,
              region: requestJSON.region
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Put item ${requestJSON.user_email}`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

EDIT

Instead of going through the complication of creating my own API and coding the Lambda function, I followed this great tutorial [Forms without servers](https://medium.com/@jbesw/forms-without-servers-handling-form-submissions-with-lambda-4df9ec5fc473) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Forms do not send data in JSON format. Forms send `application/x-www-form-urlencode` content type. You can use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object to work with the form data.

Comment: thanks @Ross - on looking deeper into the console log you were right that my web form data was being sent using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. I thought it was too complex to use URLSearchParams so instead used a great tutorial [Forms without servers](https://medium.com/@jbesw/forms-without-servers-handling-form-submissions-with-lambda-4df9ec5fc473) which created the Lambda function for me, and now it is working.